# Batch file to read a text file and search for a string. If string found return errorcode 1

Tags: batch-file

I would like to read a text file and to find a string inside the text file.
If search string is present then batch needs to be exit with `errorcode 1`.

Example:

```
Text inside a txt file would be like (123;345;678;abc)
i need to search the string / numeric value (abc or 123)
```

If found then batch should return 1.

Comment: I think `grep` is the tool you are looking for. Check out the Documentation [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/grep/)

Comment: `grep` is a Unix tool. The Windows version is [find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

According to [find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html), you should be able to perform it like this:

```
find "myTextToSearch" C:\\Path\\To\\File.txt
```

But, like you can see in documentation, these are the exit status:

> Errorlevel
>
> FIND will return an ErrorLevel as follows:
>
> 0 String found in at least one of the files.
>
> 1 String not found
>
> 2 If any files in the list do not exist or if no files match a wildcard mask.
>
> An invalid switch is given.

So either you should consider 0 (matching OK), instead of 1, either you should add post instruction to convert the status like you want.

Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

if the text file contains `abc` and/or `123`, then exit with `1`, correct?

```
findstr "abc 123" file.txt && (exit /b 1) || (exit /b 0)
```

`findstr` returns a `0`, if the string is found ("Success") or `1` if the string is not found ("Fail") (exactly the other way as you need it). If you can live with `0` for "found" and `1` for "not found":

```
findstr "abc 123" file.txt
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Optionally, you can suppress any potential matched line using `FindStr /I "ABC 123" "file.txt">Nul ...` too.